# Opengl - Draw Cylinder using texture atlas

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping

```
//component
    glRotatef((GLfloat)-90, 1, 0, 0);
    gluCylinder(qObj,t_width/2,t_width/2,t_height+2*UDwall, 20, 20);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)90, 1, 0, 0);
```

I want to draw a Cylinder attaching the part of texture.

```
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName[1]);//+
```

But not like glVertex3f, when I bind a texture that can not do by using TexCoord.
(so just whole texture printed ;ㅅ;)

First is What can I do for adjusting the part of texture.

Second is (someone suggested using texture atlas)can I change the texture's Max coord(0.0~1.0) to other number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a TextureMatrix to transform the coordinates of the texture so the desired rectangle shape (from texture altas) is in the right position.

So lets say you want to texture a rect that has coordinates `(x,y)` and dimensions `(a,b)`. What we want to achieve here is to have the texture be at `(0,0)` for `(x,y)` and `(1,1)` for `(x+a, y+b)`.

## Solution

use Texture Matrix 
translate by `(-x, -y)` 
 
scale by `(1.0 / a, 1.0 / b)`